# Count how many times a method can be called until it returns nil

Tags: ruby

Background: I need to determine the number of records in a remote location. The records are sequentially numbered (starting at `0`, no gaps) and can only be fetched one by one based on their number.

The method to fetch the records over the network returns a *truthy* value upon success and a *falsey* value upon failure. Here'a an example:

```
fetch_record(0) #=> true (record #0 exists)
fetch_record(1) #=> true (record #1 exists)
fetch_record(2) #=> true (record #2 exists)
fetch_record(3) #=> nil  (no record #3)
```

I'm trying to find an elegant way to count how many times I can call `fetch_record` with increasing argument until it returns `nil` (3 times in the above example).

**What I've tried so far**

Given this simplified implementation for testing purposes:

```
def fetch_record(index)
  raise if index > 3 # just to prevent endless loops
  true if index < 3
end
```

Here are my attempts:

1. A `while` loop with an explicit counter variable would obviously work, but I doesn't look very idiomatic:

   ```
   i = 0
   i += 1 while fetch_record(i)
   i
   #=> 3
   ```
2. I could use `step` and `break` with an explicit result value but that looks cumbersome:

   ```
   0.step(by: 1).each { |i| break i unless fetch_record(i) }
   #=> 3
   ```
3. A lazy enumerator is even worse:

   ```
   0.step(by: 1).lazy.map { |i| fetch_record(i) }.take_while(&:itself).count
   #=> 3
   ```

Is there an easier way to accomplish the above?

Comment: I wonder if it makes more sense to use a binsearch approach: Start with a reasonable number (e.q. 1), bisect that number when the result is `nil` or double if a record exists (plus some kind of tracking the biggers non `nil` value). That should be much faster than testing every single step - especially with remote calls. Apart from that: An answer to your question will be primarily opinion-based IMHO.

Comment: @spickermann the number of records is usually quite small. Regarding "primarily opinion-based" - I've asked this question because I suspect that I'm missing an obvious (idiomatic and elegant) solution. I'm not asking for "creative approaches" ;-)

Comment: quantum computer will bring you answer in `O(1)`, if you don't have one - go with binary search here `O(logn)` or linear search `O(n)` if your dataset is small.

Comment: @fl00r the question is really just about counting the number of calls until `fetch_record(i)` returns `nil`. The network stuff is an implementation detail and not relevant to the actual problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you are free to implement `fetch_record` the other way round, to return `true` for inexisting record:

```
def fetch_record index
  index >= 3
end
(0..Float::INFINITY).detect &method(:fetch_record)
#⇒ 3
```

Comment: I like `0.step(by: 1).detect { |i| !fetch_record(i) }` so you don't need to touch `fetch_record`

Comment: @Damiano, as what you have suggested is substantially different than mudsie's answer, you should post it as an answer. btw, you don't need `(by: 1)` as the default step size is `1`.

Answer (score 4):

[take_while](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-take_while) anyone?

```
records = 0.step.take_while{|i| fetch_record(i)}
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that you can call `step` without arguments.

Comment: BTW, you have to add `.count` in order to get the number of records (I'm not interested in the records themselves)

Comment: `1.step.size` is nice too.

Comment: As it's only the count that's wanted, this has the disadvantage of creating an intermediate array, unlike @Damiano's suggestion.